# Android wireless/remote debug app on another Wifi network

Tags: android, debugging, adb, wifi, remote-debugging

Is is it possible for Android development to remote debug an app from another network?
I am not talking about WebView/Web Pages debugging but as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging), as this page talks about remote debugging a WebView or web pages opened in any app and also I don't think it will work on if device and computer are on different networks.

My scenario is that if **Device A** is connected to **Computer A** on **Wifi A** and I want to debug the app running on **Device A** from **Computer B** on **Wifi B**.

There is option to connect your device using the ADB wireless debugging using TCP-IP, but that requires the Device and Computer to be on the same network, but in my case device and computer are on another network.